# Magento recently viewed products

Tags: php, mysql, magento, product, mage

What I have tried. Just get viewed products and display it, as result i got nothing:

```
 <?php $_recentlyViewed =
 Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')-> getItemsCollection(); ?>

     <?php foreach ($_recentlyViewed as $_recentlyProduct): ?>
         <?php var_dump($_recentlyProduct); ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The next thing, it was trying to display the default block, then I got nothing. In local.xml I addded:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info"> 
                <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/> 
                <block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll" after="product_recently_viewed">
                    <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
                    <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
                </block>
           </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

And

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed'); ?>
```

In view.phtml, but still I got nothing.
I checked the table in mysql, there's records about last viewd products. So my question is, what made I wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: `getSingleton` is used to call the model classes, you are trying to use it for block ?

Comment: @Prateek I used as getSingleton method, as getBlockSingleton. Nothing work well.

Comment: have you checked in system > configuration, catalog > recently viewed products that it is set to show 1+?

Comment: @PixieMedia there setted 5, for current website. It's completely strange, and I have to finish it today :(

Comment: try adding anything above the opening if statement in viewed_products to see if it atleast loading the template

Comment: @PixieMedia it doesn't load, i tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used getSingleton try using this:

```
 <?php $_recentlyViewed =
 Mage::getModel('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')-> getItemsCollection(); ?>

 <?php foreach ($_recentlyViewed as $_recentlyProduct): ?>
     <?php var_dump($_recentlyProduct); ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

By using getModel, I think your work can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

Try with this xml code in you local.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
            <block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll" after="product_recently_viewed">
                <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
                <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

It's because you don't need to have nested references to inject something in the template. If this doesn't work, then the only reason of it would be that you don't have the `product.info` handle inside the catalog.xml file, as most of themes customize that. You'll need to check inside the catalog.xml of your theme.

For the PHP code you showed, blocks are not called this way. `getSingleton` method is reserved for the loading of models in a singleton way. However, the way you passed it with fully qualified class name, you'll probable get an object of that block anyway. Just keep it in mind for future reference. Blocks are instantiated via Magento's layout model whenever needed. They should be used in that way.